# css media query not working with hiding / showing divs

Tags: css, dynamic, media-queries

Hi I am new to css media queries so please bear with me, but essentially I am trying to hide an element if the screen size is less then 940px wide using css instead of javascript.

For some reason this is hiding the element at all sizes, i can't seem to find a typo or anything, does it not work with display none?

```
@media all and (min-width: 940px) {
#smallDistrictMap
{
    display:none;
}
}
```

I noticed it is working if the screen size starts smaller then 940px but not if the screen starts at a larger size...

also tried adding max-width

```
@media all and (max-width: 2000) and (min-width: 940px) {
#smallDistrictMap
{
    display:none;
}
}
```

but this is having no effect for some reason. aaaah

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 940px)

Comment: this is still just hiding the div in firefox :(

Comment: if you want to hide it when the screen is LESS then 940 than set it the MAX width -  `@media all and (max-width: 940px) {`

Comment: lol of-course that makes total sense. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the element if the screen is less than 940px - means that 940px is the MAX, not the MIN:

```
@media all and (max-width: 940px) {
#smallDistrictMap
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was too caught up in the media query syntax that i forgot to look at what it was actually saying. lol, its time for a cup of coffee.

Comment: when THIS type of "bugs" arising - it's time to hit the bed :) The coffee won't help much

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was an error in logic.. changing the code to max-width as Zoltan suggested did the trick.

```
@media all and (max-width: 940px) {
    #smallDistrictMap
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```